# How can I use 4 different input-values in php and save form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I don't have much experience with php that's why I hope someone can help me to solve the problem.

I am trying to extend my database with new files. I need to be able to type in four different values in my form and save the form with the typed in values. If I only use the first input-tag **#inschriftennummer1**, it works. My saved form shows me what I've typed in. But I need three more inputs in order to tag the document with 4 values. If I use the code like that, no input value is shown when I save the form.

Maybe someone has a solution :)

```
 <body>
   <form name="Formular" method="post" action="">
   <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 0%;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 85%;">
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET["change"]))
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("Inschriften/".$_GET["change"].".xml");
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="inschriftennummerAlt" value="'.$xml-  >Inschriftennummer.'"/>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="change"/>';
    }
    else
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("Inschriften/Null.xml");
    }

    /*Gibt zu einem String die jeweilige Hexadezimalform zurück*/
    function strToHex($string)
    {
        $hex='';
        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
        }
        return str_replace("da", "", $hex);
    }

    /*Gibt zu einer Hexadezimalform den jeweiligen String zurück*/
    function hexToStr($hex)
    {
        $string='';
        for ($i=0; $i <strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
        {
            $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
        }
        return $string;
    }
      ?>

      <div class="main">
      <div class="meta">
      <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
       <?php
        if (strlen($_GET["inschriftennummer"] == 0))
        {
    //      echo "Bitte Inschriftennummer überprüfen.";
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="I"><span class="label">Inschriftennummer</span>:</td>
      <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="inschriftvorher" value="'.$xml- >Inschriftennummer.'">'; ?>
      <td class="II"> 
      <input name="inschriftennummer1" type="text" size="7" value="<?php echo       str_replace("_", " ", $xml->Inschriftennummer);?>"/>  
        <input name="inschriftennummer2" type="text" size="7" value="<?php echo str_replace("_", " ", $xml->Inschriftennummer);?>"/>  
        <input name="inschriftennummer3" type="text" size="7" value="<?php echo  str_replace("_", " ", $xml->Inschriftennummer);?>"/>  
        <input name="inschriftennummer4" type="text" size="7" value="<?php echo str_replace("_", " ", $xml->Inschriftennummer);?>"/>
       </td>
```

Comment: This is pretty much PHP/MySQL 101. Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: So my php form only saves the last value after I submit. Does the last input  overwrite the others because of the same input name?

Comment: Yes - names must be unique